# Flex RSL - IE shows Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Implemeting RSL in Flex 3.2

The build comils perfectly but opening it shows Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. URL:

Whereas I have confirmed the requisite files are there in the folder. i.e. SWZ/SWF. 
I also noticed we assetCache does not contains framework swz.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I modified Flex_config.xml and kept the default RSL tag uncommented.

```
 <runtime-shared-libraries> 
             <url rsl-url="framework_3.2.0.3958.swf"/> 
             <url rsl-url="framework_3.2.0.3958.swz"/>
```

This should be commented ...